# Can I re-enroll BioExcess fingerprints without Finger Convenience?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, fingerprint, biometrics

Just got a new Lenovo laptop and, like the idiot I am, typo'd my username. No problem, thinks I, I'll just remove that user and create a new one.

Unfortunately, I had already registered almost all my fingers to the typo'd account. Now, with my new, correctly spelled account, I can only "enroll" the finger that I didn't on the old account.

It seems the BioExcess®™ way to do this is to use the supplied *Finger Convenience* utility. Of course, wise old Lenovo have decided that their OEM version of BioExcess doesn't need such frivolity.

When I rang Lenovo support, I was advised to do a factory reset. This seems like nuking a nut to me; especially as I've spent several hours installing stuff by this point.

Surely there's an easier way - does anybody know it?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar problem except I enrolled fingers on a local account, joined the computer to a domain, and then deleted the local account.

My solutions was to go to the BioExcess data directory ("C:\ProgramData\Egistec\BioExcess\Data" on my computer), make a backup of the directory, delete the files (user.data and another directory with a long hex name starting with {S...), restart the computer, then redo the enrollment.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'd actually given up on this (4 years later!), but will try this approach when I get home.